# Busted Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

After six months my Raspberry Pi 4 (1Gb) stopped working. Only the red PWR-led is glowing. I checked the board and I found this busted part. I always used the original raspberry USB-C power supply and a "PI TFT 50 V2.0" display.
Any ideas what is this broken part on the board and why it is now busted?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi4/raspberry-pi-4-reduced-schematics.pdf will let you identify the part.

Comment: @joan thank you but unfortunately I do not have the ability to read this plan, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is an inductor (part of the power regulator circuitry).

This is of academic interest; if it failed it is probably over voltage or a power surge.

The end result is that the Pi is dead and the power supply is probably damaged.